How to pass a select list using partial view in .Net Core?
I have written an action for a Partial view where I am calling a select list, and have passed same in the _Layout.cshtml.
The dropdown loads on Home/Index action, but the complete website stops working when access any other Action and Controller method.
Home Contoller Action
    public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Proj = new SelectList(db.Projects.ToList(), "ProjectId", "ProjectName");
    return View();
}

_Layout.cshtml
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Home/_partial.cshtml")

I am trying to achieve to get select list and pass it in a form which opens on a button click and which is placed on header menu.

According to your description, I suggest you could use view component instead of using the partial view.
The view component could inject the service directly to get the data from database and could pass model or the viewbag to the component view which doesn't need pass all the data for all the controller mehtod.
More details about how to use it, you could refer to below example and this link :
1.Create a Component class:
public class ProjectDropdownViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        //you could modify the code to get the data from database
        List<Project> projects = new List<Project>() { new Project { ProjectId=1, ProjectName="test" }, new Project { ProjectName = "test2", ProjectId = 2 } };
        ViewBag.Proj = new SelectList(projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName");

        return View();
    }
   
}

2.Create a componment view as the below path:
Please notice: the view component view path need match as below:
/Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
/Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
/Areas/{Area Name}/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}

So please create the view as below path: Views/Shared/Components/ProjectDropdown/Default.cshtml
View code:
<select asp-items="@ViewBag.Proj" class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Select Project --</option>
    
</select>

3.Invoke it at the layout:
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProjectDropdown")

            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">CoreMVC</a>

Result:


Thank you @Brando Zhang. I created exact replica of your code in my WebApp, but no success. Getting an error as This page isnt working.


I created new folder at rootlevel as Components and created Component class in it as you mentioned in the above 1st step 2) Create a componment view as the below path Views/Shared/Components/ProjectDropdown/Default.cshtml and inserted the View Code 3) Invoke it at the layout. No Success with error This page isnt working


Thank you @Brandon Zhang, issue was in my Project Class, made correction and results are now showing as expected. Appreciate it
